# Return a tuple of arguments to be fed to format()

Tags: python

How I can fix it?

```
return 'loader:\n {}' % ''.join('{}:{}\n'.format(*(key, value) for key, value in slownik.iteritems()))
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

this should be in one line ;-)

Comment: What do you suppose `''.format(....)` is supposed to do?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I fix it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the '%', which is the old-style string formatter; drop the generator comprehension, because `iteritems` returns exactly what you need to do formatting; finally, drop the double `format`:

```
'loader:\n {0}:{1}\n'.format(*slownik.iteritems())
```

**EDIT**: ok, now I see what you want to do.

```
'loader:\n' + ''.join(' {0}:{1}\n'.format(k, v)
                      for k, v in slownik.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'loader: \n '+''.join('{0}:{1}\n'.format(k,v) for k,v in slownik.iteritems())
```